# Saving Custom Attribute in Liferay Portal 6.1

Tags: liferay

I have written a liferay portlet to learn expando/custom attributes. I have a custom attribute named nick for every user. I have this form in jsp

```
<form action='<portlet:actionURL></portlet:actionURL>' method="post">
    <liferay-ui:custom-attribute className="<%=User.class.getName()%>"
        classPK="<%=user.getPrimaryKey()%>" name="nick" editable="true" label="Nick">
    </liferay-ui:custom-attribute>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When I try to get this value in processAction using

```
String nick = request.getParameter("nick");
```

Or

```
String nick = ParamUtil.get(request, "nick", "no nick given");
```

It gives me nothing. I checked the name of this textbox comes as _testexpandoportlet_WAR_testexpandoportlet_ExpandoAttribute--nick--

How to get this in processAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code section will work

```
String nick = "";
nick = (String) PortalUtil.getExpandoValue(request,
                "ExpandoAttribute--" + "nick" + "--",
                ExpandoColumnConstants.STRING, ExpandoColumnConstants.PROPERTY_DISPLAY_TYPE_TEXT_BOX);
```

For help of others I have uploaded the portlet on Sourceforge. Link for [test-expando-portlet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/test-expando/files/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PortalUtil.getExpandoValue(...)`

```
  String expandoValue = (String)PortalUtil.getExpandoValue(request, "nick", ExpandoColumnConstants.STRING, ExpandoColumnConstants.PROPERTY_DISPLAY_TYPE_TEXT_BOX);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work as it looked. I checked the liferay source. Liferay is also getting in a similar way but with name modified. See this code..                                              String nick = (String) PortalUtil.getExpandoValue(request,
     "ExpandoAttribute--" + "nick" + "--",
     ExpandoColumnConstants.STRING,
     ExpandoColumnConstants.PROPERTY_DISPLAY_TYPE_TEXT_BOX);